# How to automatically move a window to secondary display on MacOS?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

At the end of recorded Zoom calls, a transcoding window appears for a long time, floating above all other Windows. Quite a nuisance.

I'm looking for some automated solution, eg an AppleScript that runs and checks every couple seconds whether such a window exists, and if so, moves it to display 2. Or perhaps some special software that has such a built-in feature?

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What type of window is it? Picture would help if you don't know the official designation. Some windows you can move, some you can't.

Comment: Is there a tool that allows to inspect the window type?

Comment: Eyes are usually good enough for that… hence 'post a picture' if you don't know. Trying to figure out how to interrogate a window type is way beyond consumer level… as really is trying to do this by applescript. You'd have to get some way through this yourself, & come back if you get stuck. [3rd party software recommendations are off-topic].

Comment: @Tetsujin image added

Comment: That looks very much like a modal. If you can't grab it anywhere with the mouse, it's not going to be movable.

Comment: @Tetsujin it can easily be grabbed. The question is how to automatically move it instead of manually

Comment: OK, you need to investigate GUI coding, in particular how to get the window number. It's a bit beyond my paygrade, sorry